# i keep getting an invalid qualifier error

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Option Explicit

  Sub trial()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim celladdress As String
   Dim myrange As Variant
   Dim word As Variant


   Set rng = Range("G3:G1000").Find(what:="Description")
   rng.Find what:="Description"

   celladdress = rng.Address

   Dim max As Range

    Dim b As Integer
     b = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
     Set max = Range("G2", celladdress)



   For Each word In max
        If word = "Moisture Content" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 24) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word

   For Each word In max
        If word = "Grading Class" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 16) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word
   For Each word In max
        If word = "Zone X Constituent Parts" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 17) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
  Next word
   For Each word In max
        If word = "Plastic Limit" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 18) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word
   For Each word In max
        If word = "Liquid Limit" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 19) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
  Next word
  For Each word In max
        If word = "Plasticity Index" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 20) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
  Next word
  Each word In max
        If word = "Particle Density" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 21) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word
   For Each word In max
        If word = "Optimum Moisture Content" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 22) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word
  For Each word In max
        If word = "Maximum Dry Density" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 23) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
   Next word
   For Each word In max
        If word = "Shear Strength at OMC" Then
            Cells(b + 1, 15) = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
  Next


  Dim txt As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim reference As Variant
  Dim k As Integer
  Dim c As Integer
   c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

   txt = Cells(2, 5).Value

    reference = Split(txt, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(reference)

    Cells(c + 1, 4).Value = reference(i)

   next

   txt = Cells(2, 5).Value

    reference = Split(txt, " ")
     For k = 0 To LBound(reference)

          Cells(c + 1, 9).Value = reference(k)

        Next k

         Dim Last_Row As Long


              Last_Row = Range("C3").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row

         Cells(Last_Row, [13]).Value = "Sampling"
        Range("C3").Copy Range("C" & Last_Row)
         Range("B3").Copy Range("B" & Last_Row)
         Range("A3").Copy Range("A" & Last_Row)

        Dim rnge As Range
        Dim celladdres As String


          Set rnge = Range("G3:G1000").Find(what:="Description")
           rng.Find what:="Description"

         celladdres = rnge.Address.Offset(-1, 50) - Invalid error

         Dim maxy As Range
 
         Set maxy = Range("G2", celladdress)

           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(max).Delete

   End Sub
```

Hi i keep getting an invalid qualifer error and im  unsure why. Im trying to get the find the next description and then offset the cell so i can delete all the information in the row above and 50 column along. im unsure why the error keep ocurring and what it actually means.  any help would be greatly appreicated thanks max

Comment: `rng.Offset(-1,50).Address`? You can only call `Offset` on a `Range` object. `Address` returns a `String`.

Comment: When which code line does the error appear?

Comment: celladdres = rnge.Address.Offset(-1, 50) - Invalid error FaneDuru

Comment: Hi Big Ben, so if i takeaway dim cell address as a string would this work?

Comment: No. You can't do `.Address.Offset`. You *can* do `.Offset.Address`.

Comment: Hi bigben thanks for your response, i have tried to move the offest and wrote it as celladdres = rnge.Offset(-1, 50).Address but it doesnt seem to actually of the code. Is this because its a string? Thanks for your help